# Swift Segmentation Fault in generic structure

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to implement this thing:

```
public struct Relationship<P,K> where P:Persistable, P:Hashable, K:Persistable {
    let key: String
    var value: [P]
    var parentEntity: K?

    init(key: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = []
    }
}
```

and then use it in some structure like a variable

```
public struct Test {
    var test: Relationship<Event, Test>?
}
```

and I got [image]

Dont worry Test struct does implement Persistable in an extension.
I have no idea how to work around this. Do you?
Thank you

Comment: When I try this locally I get **"error: value type 'Test' cannot have a stored property that references itself"**. Changing Test to a class, or changing Relationship to a class, avoids this problem.

Comment: Hmmm....changing Relationship doesnt help.. Test needs to be class :) thank you